# Como utilizar oninvalid no textarea [HTML5]

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Queria saber como utilizar o oninvalid no text area.

```
 <textarea type="text" pattern=".{1,255}" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" class="form-control no-resize" rows="6" placeholder="A mensagem" required maxlength="255" autofocus
     oninvalid="setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Quantidade de caracteres excedida.' : '')"></textarea>
```

Pois desta forma nao esta funcionando!

Answer (score 1):

Caro,

Para que o elemento `<textarea>` seja inválido é necessário submeter o campo dentro de um elemento `<form>`, no entanto, em sua validação apenas o atribute `required` irá validar o textarea. No **HTML5** o atributo **pattern** não está disponível para o elemento `<textarea>`, neste caso terá que validar o length na mão.

Exemplo para executar a validação:

```html
    <form>
      <textarea required oninvalid="alert('é obrigatório');"></textarea>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643417/how-to-validate-pattern-matching-in-textarea)

Abraço.